# Unable To Start Activity

Tags: java, android

//This is my LOGCAT

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                    android.app.SuperNotCalledException: Activity
>
> {com.example.agiletech.agiletech/com.example.agiletech.agiletech.Recover}
>   did not call through to super.onStart()
>                                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5134)
>                                                                                        at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2324)
>                                                                                        at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2403)
>                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:165)
>                                                                                        at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1373)
>                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
>                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
>                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5391)
>                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
>                                                                                        at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
>                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
>                                                                                        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 09-30 12:17:23.478
>   678-698/? E/AppErrorDialog: Failed to get ILowStorageHandle instance

Comment: Have you overridden onStart and removed super.onStart(); in your activity? If so, don't remove that. If no post your code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that you have super.onStart in your overridden methods